# Xamarin Firebase Sending Email Verification

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-authentication

good day how to send an email verification on Xamarin after you register an account I'm using this code but in `sendEmailVerification` it said FirebaseAuth does not define `sendEmailVerification`

how can I fix this?

```
private void LoginUser(string email, string password){

   if (input_password.Text == reinput_password.Text){

        auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

          .AddOnCompleteListener(this, this);


        auth.sendEmailVerification(email)

           .AddOnCompleteListener(this, this);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SendEmailVerification(Async)` is a method on an `FirebaseUser` instance:

#### Example (using Xamarin async wrappers):

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.Instance;
using (var authResult = await auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync("so@sushi.com", "stackoverflow"))
using (var user = authResult.User)
using (var actionCode = ActionCodeSettings.NewBuilder().SetAndroidPackageName(PackageName,true, "0").Build())
{
    await user.SendEmailVerificationAsync(actionCode);
}
```

Comment: so i have to make firebaseUser before i can send a verification?

Comment: @BogartPoe A user is created when you call `CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword|Async`, you just have to use the one returned. note: If you are trying to verify a user via "email link", that is a totally different thing.

Comment: yes i want the user to verify if with a link emailed to them how can i do that?

Comment: @BogartPoe https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth

Answer (score 0):

my code works but there is something wrong IsEmailVerified always false

```
var authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(webapi));

                        var auth = await authProvider.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(emailtxt.Text, passwordtxt.Text);
                        string gettoken = auth.FirebaseToken;
                        var content = await auth.GetFreshAuthAsync();
                        var serializedcontnet = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
                        Preferences.Set("MyFirebaseRefreshToken", serializedcontnet);

                        if(content.User.IsEmailVerified == false)
                        {
                           var action = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Your Email not activated,Do You want to Send Activation Code again?!", "Yes","No");

                            if(action)
                            {
                                await authProvider.SendEmailVerificationAsync(gettoken);
                            }

                        }
```